# copy paste a line into another file at the same position in bash

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I want to copy line 30 from one specific file and paste it into line 30 in another file. I cannot do this manually because the files are too big (20 gb+)

I have found out how to append it to the end of another file:

```
awk 'NR==30' file1.txt >> file2.txt
```

How do you specify the line for file2?

Comment: Do you want to replace existing line 30 in file2 ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't using that redirection mechanism. I would perhaps suggest a Perl script (or Awk, given that you're using Awk already), that simply reads a line, writes it, and slips the new line in at the appropriate place.

```
my $count = 0;
while (<INPUT>) {
   print OUTPUT $_;
   if ($count  == 30) {
      print OUTPUT $lineToBeInserted;
   }
   $count++;
}
```

Note how it doesn't store the whole file in memory but merely each line at a time.

Answer (score 1):

With `awk`:

```
awk '
NR==30{line=$0;next}
NR==FNR{next}
FNR==30{$0=line}1
' file1 file2 > tmp && mv tmp file2
```

Comment: Creating a temporary 20GB file seems slightly heavyweight here

Comment: @cmh and loading 20GB file into memory for "sed's in-place" editing is not heavyweight? :)

Comment: @kobame it will hit memory but not disk. It's also potentially a useful artifact for someone with a similar problem without the 20GB constraint. Given the constraints of the question, Brian's answer seems like the one to go for.

Answer (score 0):

With [sed](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?sed):

```
sed -i "30i $(sed -n '30p' file1.txt)" file2.txt
```

The inner command extracts the 30th line from file1.txt

```
target_line=$(sed -n '30p' file1)
```

The outer command inserts that text into line 30 of file2.txt

```
sed -i "30i $target_line" file2.txt
```